# Python Multithreading with nested lists loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, loops

I want to make my program more faster with using multithreading in python 3. In this case i want to make 5 threads in a second. so here the detail,

I have 2 lists which contains some unique values

```py
# list 1
countries = ['argentina', 'brazil', 'czech', 'denmark']

# list 2
# each country should have his own code below, so i make it into a dict
countries_seq = dict()
for country in countries:
   countries_seq[country] = [f'{country}{n}' for n in range(1000)]

# so we will get the result of for loop above,
# countries_seq = {'argentina': [....], 'brazil': [...], 'czech': [...], 'denmark': [...]}
```

the goal is i want to make 5 threads with passing that 2 lists to my arguments function, here my function code

```py
def submit_country(country_name: str, country_seq: str):
   # submit country code, here i request to an API
   print(f'{country_name} - {country_seq}')
```

here the full code,

```py
def submit_country(country_name: str, country_seq: str):
   print(f'{country_name} - {country_seq}')

countries = ['argentina', 'brazil', 'czech', 'denmark']

countries_seq = dict()

for country in countries:
   countries_seq[country] = [f'{country}{n}' for n in range(1000)]

# multithreading will held here
```

the question is how i can create multithreading with 5 threads, and rules every process will pass one country name to first parameter in `submit_country` function and 5 `country_seq` code in second parameter, example result:

```bash
# First process
argentina - argentina0
argentina - argentina1
argentina - argentina2
argentina - argentina3
argentina - argentina4

# Second process
brazil - brazil0
brazil - brazil1
brazil - brazil2
brazil - brazil3
brazil - brazil4

# Third process
czech - czech0
czech - czech1
czech - czech2
czech - czech3
czech - czech4

# Fourth process
denmark - denmark0
denmark - denmark1
denmark - denmark2
denmark - denmark3
denmark - denmark4

# Fifth process - it will continue `argentina` process
argentina - argentina5
argentina - argentina6
argentina - argentina7
argentina - argentina8
argentina - argentina9

...
# until end
```

i was try hard to thinking, but still i can't solve it. this is the last of the experiments i did before i create this question

```py
from threading import Thread

def submit_country(country_name: str, country_seq: str):
   print(f'{country_name} - {country_seq}')

countries = ['argentina', 'brazil', 'czech', 'denmark']

countries_seq = dict()
for country in countries:
   countries_seq[country] = [f'{country}{n}' for n in range(1000)]

# multithreading will held here
for country in countries:
  for country_seq in countries_seq[country]:
    threads = []
    for tr in range(t):
      thread = Thread(target=submit_country, args=(country, country_seq))
      threads.append(thread)
      thread.start()
    
    for tr in threads:
      tr.join()
```

code above will print `argentina` and its `country_seq` until end, then it will continue print `brazil`, then `czech`, and `denmark` like that until it's finished.

Comment: Usually, multithreading is used for IO intensive operations. Seeing there is nothing like that in the code, you can look into multiprocessing.

Comment: @RahulK i am sorry, i was fixed the last code. btw, can you give me any references ?

Comment: @RahulK What about their "here i request to an API"?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with this flow,

```py
from threading import Thread

def submit_country(country_name: str, country_seq: str):
   # request post API
   print(f'{country_name} - {country_seq}')

countries = ['argentina', 'brazil', 'czech', 'denmark']

countries_seq = dict()
for country in countries:
   countries_seq[country] = [f'{country}{n}' for n in range(1000)]

# multithreading will held here

max_thread = 5 # maximum thread
flag = True # flag in the future to stop while loop
start = 0 # initial slicing start
end = max_thread # initial slicing end

while flag:
   threads = []
   for country in countries:
      for country_seq in countries_seq[country][start:end]:
         thread = Thread(target=submit_country, args=(country, country_seq))
         threads.append(thread)
         thread.start()
     
      for thread in threads:
         thread.join()

      start = end
      end = end + max_thread
   
      if len(threads) < 1:
         flag = False
```

actually, is not same answer with the question provided. but with this answer i still got what i want to do.